# Reverse of melt and drop duplicates dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot, melt

I have a DataFrame like

```
event   entity  type
1       T1      Table
1       C1      Cell
1       C2      Cell
2       T2      Table
2       C3      Cell
```

I want to convert it to something like this

```
event   Table   Cell
1       T1      C1
1       T1      C2
2       T2      C3
```

This is the output of pd.melt and drop_duplicates() and I read that melt's opposite is pivot so tried to approach that way for a single event.

```
df.pivot_table(values='entity', index='event', columns='type')
```

but this throws error as `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate` which is obvious because pivot does a group by aggregate and doesn't replicate every combination. Any idea what exactly this kind of operation might be done with? Please note the groupby thing which I discarded for simplification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for repalce non `Table` rows to `NaN`s and forward fill missing values, then filtere out these rows with inverted mask by `~` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `rename` column and change ordering of columns:

```
m = df['type'].eq('Table')
df['Table'] = df['entity'].where(m).ffill()
df = df[~m].rename(columns={'entity':'Cell'})[['event','Table','Cell']]
print (df)
   event Table Cell
1      1    T1   C1
2      1    T1   C2
4      2    T2   C3
```